# Writing an LLVM pass out of llvm source code undefined symbols

Tags: cmake, llvm

I am trying to build an LLVM pass out of the LLVM source code. 
I have followed the instructions on http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#developing-llvm-passes-out-of-source.
The Makefiles contain the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.3)
project(SimpleProject)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -Wall -fno-rtti -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0")

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
add_subdirectory(testpass)
```

and the Makefile in the subdirectory:

```
add_library(TestPass MODULE TestPass.cpp)
```

The pass build flawlessly, but when I try to run it with

```
sudo opt load /path/to/testpass/TestPass.so TestPass < testprogram.bc > /dev/null
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error opening /path/to/testpass/TestPass.so': /path/to/testpass/TestPass.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4llvm10ModulePass17createPrinterPassERNS_11raw_ostreamERKSs
-load request ignored.
```

I am new to the LLVM system, and always have trouble with makefiles.

Comment: If you are getting undefined symbols at runtime, then you've forgotten to link against something. Most likely something like `target_link_libraries(TestPass ${LLVM_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: That didn't do it either. It's probably just a dumb mistake I overlooked but I can't find anything that helps me. Basically all I have is an emtpy LLVM Pass that does nothing and both Makefiles and it just won't work.

Comment: Don't you need `add_llvm_loadable_module` instead of `add_library` according to that manual?

Comment: According to the manual, this is only needed if you want to add the pass to the LLVM source tree later